# Integral $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} n \int ^{\frac{2}{n}} _0 f(x+\frac{1}{n})\sin (nx) dx.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be an odd real continuous function defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Evaluate $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} n \int ^{\frac{2}{n}} _0 f(x+\frac{1}{n})\sin (nx) dx.$$

After many trial and error I decided the best substitution is $u = nx - 1$, this means that $\frac{du}{dx} = n$ and our integral neatly becomes
$$\int^1 _{-1} f\left(\frac{u+2}{n}\right)\sin(u+1)du,$$
with upper and lower bounds symmetrical around zero (which didn't matter in the end). Now I'm not sure if I'm allowed to bring the limit into the integral (see a possible reason below), if so, then $f(\frac{u+2}{n})$ will tend to $f(0)$ which is a constant. And the only way I can use the odd property of $f$ is to deduce that $f(0) = -f(0) = 0.$ Hence the limit is zero.

To bring the limit into the integral, I'm thinking of using Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence theorem. Since we know that

$$f\left(\frac{u+2}{n}\right)\sin(u+1) \leq \left|f\left(\frac{u+2}{n}\right)\right|,$$
and
$$\left|f\left(\frac{u+2}{n}\right)\right| \in L(\mathbb{R}).$$

Comment: For dominated convergence you need to find an integrable upper bound independent of $n$. Can you find such a bound? It exists.

Comment: Use the fact that $|\frac {u+2} n| \leq 3$.

Comment: @Gono what if we choose the constant function $c = \max \{f(x): x\in [-1,1]\}$?

Comment: You approach is correct but your interval is not. Check Kavi's comment to see that you have to choose $x \in [0,3]$ and ofc the maximum of $|f(x)|$. And maybe you should note why this maximum exists and is finite.

Comment: @Gono Ok sorry I realised my input isn't simply $x$, I got the interval that you obtained. As for the explanation, I believe it follows from the Extreme Value theorem due to the continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. On a side note, do you see any other ways we could use the odd property of $f$?

Comment: Prove it for $f(x)=x^m$ and then apply Stone-Weierstrass

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is odd, then we can consider \begin{align} 
\frac{n}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{n}}\{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(-x-\frac{1}{n})\}\sin(nx)dx \end{align} alternatively. Note that for $0<x\leq\frac{2}{n}$, we have $2x+\frac{2}{n}\leq\frac{6}{n}$.Thus, by continuity of $f$, if n is large enough, \begin{align} \frac{n}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{n}}\{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(-x-\frac{1}{n})\}\sin(nx)dx \leq \frac{n}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{n}}\epsilon\sin(nx)dx=\frac{\epsilon}{2}\{1-\cos(2)\}, \end{align}which implies that the limit equal to $0$. The first idea come to my mind is how to use the condition of an odd function. Besides, the key point that remind me is the proof of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, which takes use of the period of the function on the torus.